# QuickBooks Online error 'console' is undefined when authorizing

Tags: quickbooks-online

In the current QuickBooks API (V3) and internet Explorer 11, the Intuit authorization JavaScript is referring to "console.log" and throwing the error. It looks like debugging code is left over from development.

```
Line: 227 Error: 'console' is undefined
```

The error happens when you click the "Connect to QuickBooks" button displayed at the `<ipp:connecttointuit>` tag. The problem appears with Internet Explorer with script debugging turned on. We don't control our customer's PCs, so we can't ask them to use a different browser or to turn debugging off.

Does anyone here have a suggestion? (Since Intuit likes to send developer support here to SO, I guess I'm hoping Intuit will see this and respond.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response from Intuit support (which doesn't solve the problem):

> We are aware of this issue with IE and our widgets.
>
> Unfortunately this has not been resolved yet as options are available with other browsers as workaround.
>
> I will provide the feedback to team again.

So, it looks like there isn't a solution yet. Any ideas from the SO community are welcome, though.